# Can a raspberry pi 3 without monitor,keyboard and mouse, send file via bluetooth to an Android device?

Tags: permissions, raspberry-pi, android-bluetooth

I wanted to send data between Android and Raspberry Pi 3 via Bluetooth.

I made a working Android program to send file from Android to Raspberry Pi 3, but I don't have any clue to make the program to receive (take data) from Raspberry Pi 3 without using any hardware on the Raspberry Pi 3 such as keyboard,mouse, and monitor.

Is it possible to make that kind of program? if yes, can you give me examples or references?

Comment: Peer review -- For clarity, do you mean you want to leave the Raspberry Pi 3 always open to receiving bluetooth connections so when someone comes along they can just connect to it from Android over bluetooth and send a file without any interaction from the Pi?

Comment: yes! so the raspberry does not need to confirm pairing request and the files inside it can be taken from Android.